# Where can I download an offline copy of the docs of an old version of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, documentation, offline

I have an internal project with a rather large codebase that uses a slightly old version of jQuery (2.1.4). I would like to put in version control a copy of the docs of this version of jQuery in case there's ever a bug in the future (this project is supposed to have a frozen code base for a long time). Is there a way to download an offline copy of the docs for safe keeping?

I know one can with [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash), but I don't have a Mac unfortuntately, and [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/) doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this is a bit dumb but I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753532/99971). There is a trick, however. For jQuery, when the feed says `x.x.x or y.y.y`, you cannot put `x.x.x` in the URL, you need the **whole** string. For me, this link worked: `http://kapeli.com/feeds/zzz/versions/jQuery/1.11.3%20or%202.1.4/jQuery.tgz`